# Last removed element from an Array/List in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, list

How do you know the last removed element from an Array/List in Java? Interviewer asked me this Question.

Comment: You write a wrapper class and keep track of the last removed element?

Comment: Did the question specify that elements were added to or removed from the array only at the end? That is, that the array was being used as a stack? Are you required to know the last removed element despite an intervening addition?

Comment: @Raedwald infact I had asked these question to her but nothing was given as hint and I am rejected by her.

Comment: Is this question so un-useful? I see its down voted. I am sorry but this question has given me a rejection.

Comment: I upvoted, but you have to consider that the question is loaded with assumptions which don't make sense. This imposes a solution which for which there is almost certainly a better solution if the real requirement is understood.  In an interview I would ask questions to find this real requirement and propose a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: A side note: just because an interviewer asked the question, does not automatically make it a question fit for stackoverflow according to the stackoverflow rules of what questions you can ask. This is a really poor question in any case and probably more of a test of your way of thinking than your knowledge of Java.

Comment: @Gimby happy to know that it is a poor question but you can't argue with interviewer and I wish I could send her your comment.

Comment: @Naresh I'm not, I'm arguing with the question being repeated here.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is what they had in mind.

```
List<String> words = ...

String word = words.remove(0);
```

The method `remove(int)` return the object removed from the list.

Comment: This only gives to the caller. How does next caller know that which Element was removed at last time from this array?

Comment: @Naresh this is not functionality available in List currently, you would need to sub class ArrayList or hack it to record this information.

Comment: I tried to explain in similar way and taking expert advice. Thx.